# Stresstest including X server

Tags: linux, x11, stress

I am looking for an application to stresstest a Linux machine. I usually use stress, but am looking fof something which also generates graphics load. Preferably easy to compile without dependencies.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[x11perf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/x11perf) is part of standard X11 distribution. Do `x11perf -all` to run all tests.

Comment: Was not aware of it. It perfectly does the job. Thanks.